# jQuery click and unbind

Tags: jquery, onclick, jquery-events, unbind

I'm not a software developer and just started learning jQuery. In the following code I add `.green` class to `.show_hide` div on click,  and I want to remove `.green` class on `.show_hide` when clicked it's again and should also close `.slidingDiv`.

```
<div><a href="#" class="show_hide">Show/hide</a></div>
<div class="slidingDiv">
Fill this space with really interesting content. <a href="#" class="show_hide">hide</a></div>​

.slidingDiv {
    height:300px;
    background-color: #99CCFF;
    padding:20px;
    margin-top:10px;
    border-bottom:5px solid #3399FF;
}
 
.show_hide {
    display:none;
}
.green {
    background: green;
}​

$(document).ready(function(){
 
    $(".slidingDiv").hide();
    $(".show_hide").show();
 
    $('.show_hide').click(function(){
        $(".slidingDiv").slideToggle();
        $(".show_hide").addClass("green");
    });    
       
});
```

Comment: Use $(".show_hide").toggleClass("green");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this, you need to use `toogleClass` function.

**Live Demo:**

http://jsfiddle.net/oscarj24/Waq4W/